# Checking HTTP Status Code in Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc

How to get the HTTP status code in Selenium?

E.g. so I can test that if the browser requests /user/27 and no user with ID=27 exists, an HTTP 404 is returned?

My primary interest is Selenium RC, but if someone knows the answer for "normal" selenium, I can probably easily translate it into RC.

/Pete

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Checking HttpResponse OK (200) with Selenium WebDriver](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14537336/checking-httpresponse-ok-200-with-selenium-webdriver)

Comment: This question is not exactly a duplicate, because when I asked the question 6 years ago, I was talking about Selenium RC which predates WebDriver. But that also makes this question rather irrelevant because I don't think people would use the old API anymore.

Answer (score 11):

This might not be the best use of Selenium for this type of test. There is unnecessary need to load a browser when you could do and have a faster running test

```cs
[Test]
[ExpectedException(typeof(WebException), UserMessage = "The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found")]
public void ShouldThrowA404()
{
    HttpWebRequest task; //For Calling the page
    HttpWebResponse taskresponse = null; //Response returned
    task = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://foo.bar/thiswontexistevenifiwishedonedayitwould.html");
    taskresponse = (HttpWebResponse)task.GetResponse();
}
```

If your test is redirecting to another page during a 404 Selenium could check the final page has what you expect.

Answer (score 5):

Since Selenium 2 includes HtmlUnit, you can utilize it in order to get access to the response directly.

```java
public static int getStatusCode(long appUserId) throws IOException {
    WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
    int code = webClient.getPage(
            "http://your.url/123/"
    ).getWebResponse().getStatusCode();
    webClient.closeAllWindows();
    return code;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately that does not work with the C# version of Selenium.

Answer (score 5):

I know this is a shocking hack, but this is what I've done:

```
    protected void AssertNotYellowScreen()
    {
        var selenium = Selenium;

        if (selenium.GetBodyText().Contains("Server Error in '/' Application."))
        {
            string errorTitle = selenium.GetTitle();

            Assert.Fail("Yellow Screen of Death: {0}", errorTitle);
        }
    }
```

It gets the job done in the situation I needed it for, although I accept it's not ideal...

Comment: I've even just resorted to looking for the word "error" in the body text. Not ideal but it gets the job done.

Comment: Yeah, I had this in mind and was looking for something better, but this looks like the way I'll have to go for now.

Answer (score 3):

You probably want to check out the captureNetworkTraffic() call. Right now it only works reliably with Firefox, unless you manually set up IE/Safari/etc to proxy traffic through port 4444.

To use it, just call selenium.start("captureNetworkTraffic=true"), and then later on in your script you can call selenium.captureNetworkTraffic("...") where "..." is "plain", "xml", or "json".

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it, but if you don't mind limiting yourself to Firefox, and installing Firebug and Netexport, then Selenium can get access to the page status code (and everything else in Firebug's Net panel): http://selenium.polteq.com/en/using-netexport-to-export-firebugs-net-panel/

Answer (score -2):

If all else fails you could adapt your server side code, during testing, to output the HTTP status in the page as an element:

For example, on my 403 Permission Denied page, I have:

```
   <h1 id="web_403">403 Access Denied</h1>
```

which can be easily checked via the WebDriver API:

```
    public boolean is403(WebDriver driver) {
        try {
            driver.findElement(By.id("web_403"));
            return true;
        } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

https://rogerkeays.com/how-to-get-the-http-status-code-in-selenium-webdriver

Comment: this is **not** checking the HTTP response code, but checking the text content of an element on a page

Answer (score -2):

Try this, people

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
int countRepeats = 120; // one wait = 0.5 sec, total 1 minute after this code
boolean haveResult = false;
try {
    HtmlPage pageHndl = wc.getPage(Urls);
    for(int iter=0; iter<countRepeats; iter++){
        int pageCode = pageHndl.getWebResponse().getStatusCode();
        System.out.println("Page status "+pageCode);
        if(pageCode == 200){
            haveResult = true;
            break;
        }
        else{
            Thread.sleep(500);
        }
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
}
```