# How to get web page status code by selenium RC using C#?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-rc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Checking HTTP Status Code in Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354827/checking-http-status-code-in-selenium)

I need to get web page status code by selenium RC using C#. Actually i need to get it after clicking on some link:

selenium.Click("http://www.google.com");

Can someone help me with this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can't.  Selenium RC doesn't record that information.